# how to shorten jquery syntax if-else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using a lot of these:

```
$text = $menu.jqmData('menu-text') ? 
           $menu.jqmData('menu-text') : self.options.menuTxt;
```

It already is the "shorthand" syntax, but I'm wondering, whether it's possible to reduce the above line even further. There must be a better way than checking for *$menu.jqmData('menu-text')* and then writing the whole thing again. Isn't there?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A shorter way is to use the double pipe. It basically uses the second value if the first is `falsy`.

```
$text = $menu.jqmData('menu-text') || self.options.menuTxt;
```

You can also use it multiple time in the same line. Let's say you had a variable `uberMenuTxt` which takes priority over the other two and you could do it like so.

```
$text = uberMenuTxt || $menu.jqmData('menu-text') || self.options.menuTxt;
```

It basically keeps on going every time the current value is `falsy` and will stop at the first that is not.

Comment: Question: which one precedes the other one, if both return a value. First one, like in a normal if statement, correct?

Comment: @frequent yes, this is how the || (OR) works. if the first statement returns true, the following aren't evaluated anymore.

Comment: @gillesc - if you take late follow-up questions: I'm using the above syntax a lot now, but I'm sitting on one snippet, where the first element should have priority, but in some instances turn out to be [] empty. In that case the script breaks, because the 2nd fallback value is not taken. Question: does this also work if the first part is []?

Comment: This can be dangerous when dealing with text because if the result of the first branch is any falsy value like "0" it will give you the second branch.

Comment: @Christoph this is not exactly true, `"0"` is a truthy value. However `0` and `""` (empty string) are falsy and thus yield the wrong result. This why this method to "emulate" an if-else-condition is not very recommended.

Comment: @frequent you should use this very cautiously for the reason i stated above.

Comment: @Christoph - I have to admit, I'm mostly staying with the long version, because I often got strange results when not doing so.

Comment: @frequent you can read more about that here: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/ to understand why sometimes you get strange results.